# Redux reducer doesn't cause re-render after mapping to new array or using immer

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, immer.js

In my redux reducer I map over state and copy internal items, then return the list, the list should be a new reference so the reducer should cause a re-render on change, but it doesn't.

The code below does not cause a re-render.

```js
const initialState: Group[] = [];

export default function activeGroups(state = initialState, action: AnyAction) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'groups/createPod/fulfilled': {
      // append the new pod into the active group that matches the groupId
      const { pod, groupId } = action.payload;
      const newState = state.map((group) => { // Map to new list
        if (group.id === groupId) {
          return {
            ...group, // Not mutating original state, copying the state into new list 
            pods: [pod, ...group.pods],
          };
        }
        return group;
      });
      return newState; // This does not cause a re-render, why?
    }
```

I've tried `produce` from `immer`

```js
case 'groups/createPod/fulfilled': {
  // append the new pod into the active group that matches the groupId
  const nextState = produce(state, (draft) => {
    const group = draft.find((e) => e.id === action.payload.groupId);
    if (group) {
      group.pods.unshift(action.payload.pod);
    }
  });
  return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(nextState)); // Even tried this 
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that since 2019 you should generally not be writing reducers by hand, but use the official Redux Toolkit, which also has immer included already. See [Why Redux Toolkit is how to use Redux today](https://redux.js.org/introduction/why-rtk-is-redux-today)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. Redux is re-rendering as normal. The problem was unrelated to Redux.

It was because the object I was trying to update was being passed as a navigation param in react native, and this does not update with state changes (the reference is to the object passed through navigation, not to the Redux state).

Using `useSelector()` solves it.